# How big can the string class in C++ get?

Tags: c++, string

I think the error has to do with my string being too large.  If the function worked correctly, I doubt that I would be anywhere near the max string size (unless that really is the problem?  I doubt it because this is for a HW assignment and we need to return `output` with the song lyrics).  What is throwing this error?  How big can the string get?

Error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'  
what():  basic_string::_S_create 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Function:

```
string generateSong(string list[], int num)
{
   string output;

   for(int count = 0; count <= num; count++)
      output += list[count] + " bone connected to the "
      + list[count + 1] + " bone\n";

   return output;
}
```

Contents of `list[]`:

```
string list[9] =
   {
      "toe",
      "foot",
      "leg",
      "knee",
      "hip",
      "back",
      "neck",
      "jaw",
      "head"
   };
```

`num` is 9.  Is `output` really becoming too big?  Everything compiles fine (using g++).

Comment: Does `list[]` contain 11 items?

Comment: `list[]` contains 9 items.  I will put the items in the OP.

Comment: iterate till count<num instead of count<=num

Comment: No, the problem is not the size of the string itself, 400 characters isn't hardly big in computer size. If num is the amount of actual strings in the list, then you should iterate `count < num-1` (as you're accessing count+1)

Comment: @Pramod I tried that but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @felipemaia That's what I thought.  However, sending 7 to `num` works fine but when I send a number greater than 7 to `num`, I get the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual problem with your code is here:

```
for(int count = 0; count <= num; count++)
                     //  ^^^ problem!
```

It should be `count < (num-1)`, because you're using `list[count + 1]` in the loop-body.

Comment: Made the change you suggested but no dice.  Still getting the same error.

Comment: @Eegabooga: Sorry. It should be `count < (num-1)`.

Comment: Ah! `count < (num-1)` fixed the problem! Thank you so much. I should have remembered that `list[9]` would have been the 10th item in the array. Woops

Comment: @Eegabooga: The moral here: If in doubt, blame yourself, and not the library or the compiler or anyone else. Whenever you're tempted to write, "this [standard component] is bugged", take a deep breath, and reword it as "Where do I fail to understand how to use [...]". If nothing else it'll put you in a better mental state to reason about your own knowledge and understanding.

Comment: @Eegabooga: And if you still cannot find the problem, take a walk. Go to your local water dispenser or coffee machine, make short talk with your colleagues. The goal is to clear your mind, so that you can come back fresh.

Answer (score 3):

As you're accessing `list[count + 1]`, you can only iterate from 0 to num - 1.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of `std::string` is defined my its `max_size()` function.

Try this:

```
std::string s;
std::cout << s.max_size();
```